# ZK + Maven with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, zk

I have a problem when i try to make a new maven project
this error message happen on pom.xml file
this is the error message

> Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:pom:2.2 from http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of zkmaven has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:pom:2.2 from/to zkmaven (http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2/): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.

Please help me how to solve this.
Thank you

Comment: Try to delete .m2 directory and run maven command again

Comment: The error indicates you are 'not authorized' to transfer the artifact from http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2/. Ignoring the 'authorized' concept for the moment, the thing that strikes me is that the artifact is not a ZK artifact - it should be accessible from Maven Central. Can you update your question with **the relevant parts** of your pom file so we can see what's happening.

Comment: if i ignore the authorize then there is no problem? am i right?